# Historical regression manhwa involving a courtroom scene in which the female lead argues well

Tags: story-identification, manga

I don't remember much. In the beginning of the story the female lead is shown to be killed by this guy with black hair who I think is her fiance or husband. So she dies and then wakes up again to be be in the past. She wants to break of her relationship with the male lead.

One scene I remember was that of a court room. The female lead argues well and the male lead is impressed.
I would like to add that I'm not sure if this guy is even the male lead or not as I only read a few chapters.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE. If you remember any extra details please [edit] them into your question. When and where did you read this? Was it in colour or black and white?

Comment: The checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875) and [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337) might help if you're struggling to remember things

Comment: I think I know what this is, but the courtroom scene I recall is 20-30 chapters in, which I wouldn't describe as "a few chapters". Could you put a number to how many you read? Or, alternatively, did you skip around? I can try to find the scene in case I'm misremembering. In the meantime, do you remember how her husband kills her? And is she staying in a relationship with her husband that tried to kill her?

Comment: My inlaws are obsessed with me - court scene is in chapters 61-63. She doesn't say anything, and the male lead doesn't congratulate her. So it's not that after all. Only other court scene I know of is Lady Evony, but that's not a reincarnation story, and she's the one on trial for killing her husband (and he stays dead).

Comment: @user170206 - Someone using a different account with the same name as yours has attempted to edit this question. If that person is you and you've lost access to the account you used to post this question, please merge your new account with the previous one by following the instructions provided [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). Doing so will enable you to edit this question without approval from others, post comments within this thread, and mark an answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), if you wish to do so.